# Oracle 11g LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle11g

Мы используем Oracle Database 11g Standard Edition. Можно ли в этой версии БД реализовать следующую ситуацию:

Есть такой JOIN:

```
LEFT JOIN P_SCNMTR_LOG ON P_SCNMTR.ID_SCNMTR = P_SCNMTR_LOG.ID_SCNMTR_LOG_SCNMTR
```

Необходимо получить только первую запись для каждого `P_SCNMTR` отсортированную по `LOG_DATE`, при этом, чтобы в выборке запроса, Oracle использовал индексы. Или другими словами, нужно сгруппировать все записи по `ID_SCNMTR_LOG_SCNMTR`, затем отсортировать по `LOG_DATE`, и получить первую запись. Всё это нужно сделать внутри `JOIN`, так как данные действия необходимо выполнять несколько раз в одном запросе для разных таблиц.

Пример запроса, как это делается сейчас:

```
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT * FROM
    (
      SELECT P_SCNMTR_LOG.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY ID_SCNMTR_LOG_SCNMTR ORDER BY LOG_DATE DESC) RN FROM P_SCNMTR_LOG
      WHERE LOG_DATE <= :maxDate AND (ID_SCNMTR_LOG_DEPRTM = :idDepartment
                                      OR (ID_SCNMTR_LOG_DEPRTM = :idDepartmentFrom AND LOG_DATE < :sendDate))
    ) WHERE RN = 1
) P_SCNMTR_LOG ON P_SCNMTR_LOG.ID_SCNMTR_LOG_SCNMTR_SEC = P_SCNMTR_SEC.ID_SCNMTR_SEC
                  AND P_SCNMTR_LOG.ID_SCNMTR_LOG_LOGACT != 2
```

Проблема в том, что данный запрос всегда использует FULL SCAN, и по всей видимости нет возможности этого избежать из-за подзапроса в `LEFT JOIN`.

В Oracle Database 12c есть возможность сделать то, что нам надо, но мы располагаем Oracle Database 11g Standard Edition.

Comment: На 100% не гарантирую, но мне кажется, составной индекс по `(ID_SCNMTR_LOG_SCNMTR, LOG_DATE)` спасет отца русской демократии.

Comment: @Dmitry, а почему вы считаете, что еще два поля `ID_SCNMTR_LOG_LOGACT` и `ID_SCNMTR_LOG_DEPRTM`  участвующие в подзапросе не стоит добавлять в индекс?

Comment: `ID_SCNMTR_LOG_LOGACT` - не вижу смысла, оно стоит в условии `ID_SCNMTR_LOG_LOGACT != 2`. А остальное - посмотрел повнимательнее, пожалуй, я сейчас не готов сказать, что именно поможет. Пробовать надо и планы смотреть.

Comment: Наверное имеется ввиду корреляционный подзапрос в правой части join. Да, они только с 12.01. Для 11g попробуйте функцию first вместо row_number, [я как-то писал про это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35255271/sql-how-to-limit-a-join-on-the-first-found-row/45859241#45859241).  Но освободится от full table scan это не поможет.  Смотрите планы, почему не работает ограничение самого подзапроса.

Answer (score 2):

Если надо получить не все столбцы первой записи, то запрос можно улучшить ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=dd99fc53d3deb96331b6df214f9f0779)):

```
create table t1 (id, name) as 
    select rownum, 'item '||rownum from dual connect by level<=3;    
create table t2 (id, tid, text, created) as 
    select rownum, t1.id, 'text '||rownum, date'2021-08-01'+(0.3*rownum)  
    from t1, (select rownum rn from dual connect by level<=3);

select *
from t1 a
left join (
    select tid, 
        max(text)    keep (dense_rank first order by created desc) text,     
        max(created) keep (dense_rank first order by created desc) created     
    from t2 
    group by tid) b on b.tid = a.id;

        ID NAME     TEXT     CREATED            
---------- -------- -------- -------------------
         1 item 1   text 7   2021-08-03 02:24:00
         2 item 2   text 8   2021-08-03 09:36:00
         3 item 3   text 9   2021-08-03 16:48:00
```

> В Oracle Database 12c есть возможность сделать то, что нам надо [...]

Введённые в 12c корреляционные подзапросы в правой части соединения, были бы здесь как нельзя кстати. В 11g их можно уже попробовать ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5a9c9b8d0d148893b17c9354a7ea6579)):

```
alter session set events '22829 trace name context forever';

select a.*, b.text, b.created
from t1 a, lateral (
    select 
        max(text)    keep (dense_rank first order by created desc) text,     
        max(created) keep (dense_rank first order by created desc) created     
    from t2 b 
    where b.tid = a.id)(+) b
```

**Важно:** в продуктивной среде настоятельно не рекомендуется использовать скрытые, не документированные возможности.

---

> при этом, чтобы в выборке запроса, Oracle использовал индексы [...]
> Проблема в том, что данный запрос всегда использует FULL SCAN

- Написание запросов делится на две фазы:

  1. написанее понятного кода запроса и получение ожидаемого результата
  2. оптимизация запроса с целью достижения наивысшей производительности

  У того, кто в силу своего достаточного практического опыта может обьединить выше перечисленные фазы, вряд ли возникнет потребность задать здесь вопрос.
- FULL SCAN не означает автоматически, что запрос не достаточно производителен.
- Для оптимизация запроса необходима более полная информация: структура данных и сами данные макс. приближенные к реальным, сущ. индексы, планы выполнения и тд. Так как в вопросе эта информация отсутствует, обсуждать производительность запроса имеет мало смысла.